# File upload size limit

Tags: php, upload

I have problem with uploading files via http on sites.
Problem is that I can not upload files larger than about 126 KB. Problem is I believe server related because I have few sites on VPS and on all I have same problem.

For example if I try to upload files using widely used PHP contact form, or trough CMS on sites I just get error 500 or 404 page when I try to upload any file larger than about 126-127 KB.
If file is smaller, everything is OK.

I uploaded larger files before. I can not tell when this started because I did not tried to upload files for few months.
Only I can think off is that it worked before few months before setting PHP with mod_fcgi (maybe this is not relevant at all).

Also there is no any errors, there is no error_log in root of site, or in any other folder.

Is there anything I can check?

System info:
2 GB RAM
CPU is a dual quad-core E5440 Xeon (2.83GHz).

Running Linux 2.6.18-028stab099.3, x86_64.

Apache/2.2.22
(Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1   mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_fcgid/2.3.6
PHP/5.3.10

```
memory_limit is 96M
upload_max_filesize 32M
post_max_size 8M
max_execution_time 30
max_input_time 60
```

Comment: Check where PHP store tempfiles during upload. Looks like PHP hasn't enough space to store tempfile.

Comment: Do you mean on "upload_tmp_dir" in php.ini? It is set to default.

Comment: I am using about 30% of my VPS space limit.

Comment: Is there anything else I should look at?

Comment: Also "session.save_path" is set to "/tmp".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing MB to M on your `upload_max_filesize` line.

See [this reference in the php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes).

Not sure if php is ignoring the B or not but it is worth a try.

Comment: It is just M, not MB. I can see "upload_max_filesize 32M" in PHP Configuration Editor (which write php.ini). But thanks, any other solution maybe, I still have this problem.